# Mackey topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

> Recall that for a Hausdorff locally convex space $X$ the **Mackey topology** $\tau (X^*,X)$ is the topology in its topological dual $X^*$ of uniform convergence on all weakly compact absolutely convex subsets of $X$.

Does this definition amount to saying the following?

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the family of absolutely convex and $\sigma (X,X^{*})$-compact subset of $X$
let $\{x_n^*\}_n\subset X^*$ be a sequence  and $x^*\in X^*$ then :

$$
x_n^*\overset{\tau (X^*,X)}{\longrightarrow} x^* \Longleftrightarrow \forall K\in \mathcal{C}~:~\text{$x_n^* \longrightarrow x^*$  uniformly on $K$}
$$

Comment: Yes, in the sense that the definition implies that this is what it means for a sequence to converge.

Comment: But no in the sense that the definition also says something similar about convergence of nets/filters which is (in general) not equivalent to a statement about convergence of sequences alone.

Comment: @johannes_Hahn I did not understand the definition enactment of Mackey topology, can you explain to me what do they mean by : " the  Mackey topology on $ X^*$  is the topology in its topological dual $X^*$ of uniform convergence on all weakly compact absolutely convex subsets of $X$".